# How to prevent null/whitespace value in Windows Form textbox (using Powershell)?

Tags: winforms, powershell, validation, textbox

I made a Windows Form (this is the last portion of it) that allows the user to enter a search term in a textbox.  The whole script checks a server for log files, and downloads them to the user's machine.  The textbox data contains a string (date, account #, etc.)...and if left blank it is treated as a wildcard, downloading every log file in the folder chosen.  I'm not sure if I can disable the "ok" button until data is entered or give a pop-up/message box prompting the user to enter a search term?  I left the prior code/variables out of this example, as it has no bearing on the issue.  I appreciate any help in advance!

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "Enter search criteria"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$label.Text = "Enter search term"
$form.Controls.Add($label) 

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$form.Controls.Add($textBox) 

$form.Topmost = $True

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $Search = $textBox.Text
    $Search
}
$UserPath = "C:\GetFiles\getfiles"
& cmd /c $UserPath" "$Search
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Thank you to [Thom Schumacher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4991132/thom-schumacher) for helping me with the syntax necessary to complete this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "Enter search criteria"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$label.Text = "Enter loan number or date to search"
$form.Controls.Add($label) 

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$form.Controls.Add($textBox) 

$form.Topmost = $True

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
do
{
    $result = $form.ShowDialog()
    if  ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($textbox.text))
        {   
            Write-Warning 'Please enter search term.'
        }
}
until(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($textbox.text))
    {
    }

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $Search = $textBox.Text
    $Search
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here would be one way you could handle it.

```
$okbutton.enabled = $false # make this a default

if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($textbox.text)) #only enable when you have text in the text box
    {
    $okbutton.enabled = $true
    }
```

You'll have to use an event from the textbox to change the value of the $okbutton to enabled once text has been entered. I believe this is the event you'll need: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2

Depending on what you are doing you may need some of the other events as well.